# MySQL SUM() based on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I need help rewriting a query. I currently have a single table 'leaderboard' with 4 fields

```
+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| profileid | scoretotal | matchwon | datematchplayed |
+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+
```

im trying to create a 'ladder' view that shows me a distinct list of profileids with the 'ladderscore' being the total score from a profileids best 20 matches in the past 21 days.

The statements i have below give me the right output, but is there any way to rewrite this so it doesnt use the drop/create temptable?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS templeaderboard;
CREATE TABLE templeaderboard (INDEX(id), INDEX(profileid)) AS
( SELECT * FROM realleaderboard WHERE datematchplayed > unix_timestamp() - 1814400 ) ;

SELECT a.profileid, SUM(IF(a.matchwon = 1, a.scoretotal * 1.5, a.scoretotal)) AS ladderscore
FROM templeaderboard AS a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM templeaderboard AS b
       WHERE b.profileid = a.profileid AND b.scoretotal >= a.scoretotal) <= 20
GROUP BY a.profileid
ORDER BY ladderscore DESC;
```

Comment: try creating views?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that all your temporary table is doing is reducing the total rows of the actual table.

If that's correct, you should achieve the same moving that `where` clause you have in the temporary table to the final query and changing the final query's `where` condition to a `having`.

```
SELECT  a.profileid,
        SUM(IF(a.matchwon = 1, a.scoretotal * 1.5, a.scoretotal)) AS ladderscore
FROM   realleaderboard AS a
JOIN   realleaderboard AS b
ON     a.profileid = b.profileid and b.scoretotal >= a.scoretotal
WHERE  a.datematchplayed > unix_timestamp() - 1814400 AND
       b.datematchplayed > unix_timestamp() - 1814400
GROUP BY a.profileid
HAVING count(*) <= 20
ORDER BY ladderscore DESC;
```

This may need some tweaking, but it should give you the general idea.